# Is my antenna faulty?

Tags: rf, circuit-design, antenna, rfid

I'm trying to build a receiver signal circuit that will operate at 125khz. I'm using [this receiver chip](http://www1.futureelectronics.com/doc/AUSTRIAMICROSYSTEMS/AS3933-BQFT.pdf) and [this 125khz antenna](https://www.electrokit.com/en/product/rfid-antenna-9x12cm-125khz/). I tried breadboarding:

After connecting AS3933's **VCC, GND, CS, SCL, SDI, SDIO** pins appropriately to the Arduino, I connected one end of my square antenna to the AS3933's **LF1P** pin and the other end to Arduino's **GND** pin.

I then ran [this code](https://github.com/LieBtrau/arduino-as3933/blob/master/examples/test1/test1.ino) to check my AS3933's functionality. This is the message that I've got in my Serial Monitor :

```
test1: Checking AS3933 functionality

Tuning antenna LF1
Testing bit 4:
Frequency: 50

Testing bit 3:
Frequency: 50

Testing bit 2:
Frequency: 50

Testing bit 1:
Frequency: 50

Calibration for antenna 1 fails
```

Now from my understanding my AS3933 is functioning properly, but my antenna is at 50khz frequency for some reason. In the [description](https://www.electrokit.com/en/product/rfid-antenna-9x12cm-125khz/) it says that it is in fact 125KHZ antenna. Is the antenna that I've received faulty?

Comment: Show the **schematic** so that we can be sure that the hardware side is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your antenna: -

[image]

And to make it work in your application circuit, you'll probably need something like 1.5 nF of capacitance in parallel (or series) with it. 1.5 nF and 1.03 mH produces a tuned frequency of around 128 kHz. You would then add a little bit more in parallel with the 1.5 nF to tweak it to 125 kHz operation.

But your inductor doesn't have a data sheet so what I've written is my best (somewhat informed) guess.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try it out! Btw what values in the inductor datasheet would you find helpful (besides inductance and resistance)?

Comment: If it had a data sheet I’d just be looking for general recommendations about best usage and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the entire system is working, the emissions of switching power supplies will easily overload the amplifiers.

So experiment with changing the orientation of ALL your power supplies, and moving the AC_line cords.

At 125,000Hz you need thick copper foil, or aluminum plates, or steel sheets, to greatly reduce fields.

Comment: I don't recall seeing many RFID readers encased in thick metal.